# C Segmentation fault when I try to enqueue

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, queue, producer-consumer

I'm making a producer/ consumer model where the producers need to enqueue `int` values and the consumers dequeue them. Whenever I try to enqueue an `int`, I get a segmentation error.

Here is the relevant queue code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int item;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct Queue {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    void (*enqueue) (struct Queue* queue, int value);
    int (*dequeue) (struct Queue* queue);
    int (*queueEmpty) (struct Queue* queue);
    int size;
} Queue;

void enqueue (Queue* queue, int item){
    Node* n = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));
    n->item = item;
    n->next = NULL;

    if (queue->head == NULL) { // no head
        queue->head = n;
    } else{
        queue->tail->next = n;
    }
    queue->tail = n;
    queue->size++;
}

Queue* newQueue(){
    Queue* queue;
    queue->size = 0;
    queue->head = NULL;
    queue->tail = NULL;
    queue->enqueue = &enqueue;
    queue->dequeue = &dequeue;
    queue->queueEmpty = &queueEmpty;
    return queue;
}
```

Then I have this as a shared resource in the `prodcons.c` file:

```
Queue* queue;
```

Initialization in `main`:

```
queue = newQueue();
```

Producer code:

```
void* producer(void* arg) {

    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= n; x++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        while(queueSize(queue) == maxsize){
            pthread_cond_wait(&lock, &empty)
        }
        enqueue(queue, x);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
      return(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You are not allocating any memory for the Queue. `Queue* queue;` should be `Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));`

Comment: Also, in enqueue, although you check if the queue has a head, you don't check if the queue has a tail. The enqueue code seems to be used on an empty queue, but does not initialize that tail, resulting  in queue->tail being NULL when you use queue->tail->next.

Comment: @Misha He only does that when `head` is non-NULL. The first time you enqueue something, it sets both `head` and `tail`, so that should be safe (unless `dequeue` causes this condition to change).

Comment: @Barmar Looks like you're right. Either way, your comment identified the bug.

Comment: I think Johnny Mopp's comment identified the bug.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp When i use Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue)), i get an error saying: "invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Queue'". Any ideas?

And also, thanks for the responses everyone!

Comment: @user3591210 Where are you put that `queue = malloc(...)` statement? It should be in your `newQueue()`.

Comment: @LeeDuhem That was it! Unfortunately i'm still getting a seg fault with when i try to enqueue an item.

Comment: @user3591210 Then there must be other bugs in the code that you does not show at here.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: You should consider converting your comment into an answer so that you get the credit you deserve.

Comment: `enqueue(queue, x);` should be `queue->enqueue(queue, x);` , if I understand your design right

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401243/c-segmentation-fault-when-i-try-to-enqueue/23401793?noredirect=1#comment35854641_23401243) above, the segmentation fault is caused here:

```
Queue* newQueue(){
    Queue* queue;
    queue->size = 0;   /**** Seg-fault ****/
```

The newly defined Queue pointer 'queue' has not been set to point at anything in particular.  Hence, it is likely pointing at some bizarre memory location that doesn't actually exist.

Treated as though it is pointing at a legitimate location, the code tries to zero 'queue->size'.  When the processor calculates "bizarre memory location" + "the offset of the size element within the `struct queue`", it ends up with an address that is not listed in the process' memory map.  This causes an unrecoverable error known as a Segmentation Fault.

---

**FIX:**

Change:

```
Queue* newQueue(){
    Queue* queue;
```

To:

```
Queue* newQueue(){
Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));
   /* Check here if malloc() was successful */
```

Comment: I agree your answer identifies the problem and provides a decent solution, and mentions the necessary error checking.  I'm just not sure whether you should get the credit when Johnny Mop pointed out the problem over an hour before you created this answer.  Were it me, I'd probably create a Community Wiki answer and link to the comment that identified the problem — but I accept that the constraints on me are slightly different from the constraints on you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, understood.  I am somewhat new to StackOverflow; and as of yet, I have not looked into the 'Community Wiki answer' side of things.  I will work on figuring that out.  In the meantime, I have edited my answer to acknowledge Johnny Mopp's insightful comment.  Thank you for your guidance.